# Running Invoke-WebRequest as System account

Tags: powershell

I want to run Invoke-WebRequest as System in a scheduled task.

The cmdlet fails with the following error:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the
>   Internet  Explorer engine is not available, or Internet Explorer's
>   first-launch  configuration is not complete. Specify the
>   UseBasicParsing parameter and try  again.

I don't want to use UseBasicParsing because I need the ParsedHtml object from the response. How can I make this work?

Comment: I wonder if [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://superuser.com/a/1698097) addresses this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there are no workarounds except using `-UseBasicParsing` - you can access the HTML with the `.RawContent` Property.

As an alternative, create a service user, log on one time and configure IE and then use that user for your scheduled task.

Comment: As an alternative, they can use an html parsing lib like HtmlAgilityPack.  The problem with service users is password rotations and broken tasks.

Comment: For HTML parsing OK, but the user has the problem that the invoke-webrequest doesn't work - so there is no HTML to parse.

Comment: Yes, but they expressed they need the parsed html so `-UseBasicParsing` wasn't an option.  I'm providing an alternative where they get both of the things they need: parsed html and a working task.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the browser is waiting on a human to run the initial configuration wizard.  You can run the following Powershell to add a registry entry to disable waiting on that wizard to run.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" -Name "DisableFirstRunCustomize" -Value 1

Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" -Name "DisableFirstRunCustomize" -Value 1
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-ie-internetexplorer-disablefirstrunwizard

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it was at the top of Google results, so I thought it would be helpful for others to answer this.
The way we worked around this issue is to use psexec to run iexplore.exe and click through the IE first-run dialogs.

```
./psexec.exe -sid "$Env:ProgramFiles\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Now you can use Invoke-WebRequest from a scheduled task running as the local system account.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why you would run anything connecting to the Internet as System. You should really run as a lower privileged account. That being said, MrRat's solution was the easy solution when running a script in context of a service account. When developing, PoweShell script worked fine interactively as the developer with no special local privileges but failed when running as a gMSA. Tearing through the Exception, I found this:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal Source: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility   
StackTrace: at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.VerifyInternetExplorerAvailable(Boolean checkComObject)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand.ProcessResponse(WebResponse response)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

It was the `VerifyInternetExplorerAvailable(Boolean checkComObject)` piece that ultimately led me here to find a solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34415788)

Comment: I didn't say anything about connecting to the Internet.